# Joining two CSV in Scala

Tags: scala

I have 2 sets of data.

TestScala1.txt

1,Dom,Torreto
2,Lety,Betty
3,Bob,Dylan
4,Taio,Cruz
5,Dan,Perez
6,Jen,Rose

TestScala2.txt

1,Red,27,Makati
2,Blue,22,Pasig
3,Pink,25,Pateros
4,Black,12,Laguna
5,Orange,20,Pasay

I'm trying to join both files through a key using 1st column.
So far, this is what i currently have

```
import scala.collection.mutable._  
import scala.collection.immutable._  
import java.io.PrintWriter  
import scala.io.Source  

object readwritefile {
  def main(args: Array[String]){

    val id = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
    val fname = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
    val lname = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
    val color = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
    val age = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
    val city = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()

    val textFromFile1 = Source.fromFile("testScala1.txt", "UTF-8")
    val textFromFile2 = Source.fromFile("testScala2.txt", "UTF-8")

    // Get key from source file
    for(line <- textFromFile1.getLines) {
        val arr = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
        id(arr(0).toInt) = arr(0)
        fname(arr(0).toInt) = arr(1)
        lname(arr(0).toInt) = arr(2)
    }

    // Join to source(2)
    for(line <-textFromFile2.getLines) {
      val arr = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
      if (id.contains(arr(0).toInt))
        color(arr(0).toInt) = arr(1)
        age(arr(0).toInt) = arr(2)
        city(arr(0).toInt) = arr(2)
    }

    id.keys.toSeq.sortBy(id).foreach{ key =>
      printf(s"id: ${id(key)} name: ${fname(key)} surname:${lname(key)} color:${color(key)} age:${age(key)} city:${city(key)}\n")
    }
    textFromFile1.close()
    textFromFile2.close()
  }
}
```

The main cause of my problem is that the two files are not equal in count, therefor causing an error since scala does not allow it.
Is there any way i can join two files even if the row count is not equal?

EDIT: Here is the error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 6
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.apply(HashMap.scala:65)
    at readwritefile$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcVI$sp(readwritefile.scala:37)
    at readwritefile$$anonfun$main$1.apply(readwritefile.scala:36)
    at readwritefile$$anonfun$main$1.apply(readwritefile.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at readwritefile$.main(readwritefile.scala:36)
    at readwritefile.main(readwritefile.scala)
```

What my script does is store all col(0) keys to id. Since testScala2.txt does not have id #6, i think this is what causes the problem.
May main goal is to join both files to a single output.

Comment: Please be more specific, what error do you get? The `cause` of your problem is NOT `because the two files are not equal`, that's just a fact, you are gonna need to provide an actual problem so people can point you to the cause. Also it's gonna be very ambiguous (even maybe for senior Scala developers) and difficult to figure out what you mean by `scala does not allow it`.

Comment: Also the title does not fit the question, even if the question was not incomplete it wouldn't have been about `joining two CSV files in Scala` rather about a specific problem you were facing with your code.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, my main goal is to join both files through the 1st column(id). Edited the post for the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my problem is that the two files are not equal in count, therefor causing an error since scala does not allow it

You don't post any error message here, so I guess that your code blows up when executing the print statement, right? This is because if you just try to get a value based on a key (e.g. the `color(key)`), and if the key doesn't exist, then it will throw `NoSuchElementException`. Since it's expected that some of the key might be missing (because the two files don't have the same number of row), you should use `getOrElse()`, e.g. `color.getOrElse(key, "")` to avoid exception.

Btw, your code has an copy/paste error at `city(arr(0).toInt) = arr(2)` - it should have been `city(arr(0).toInt) = arr(3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is exactly my problem. If you don't mind, can you please help me on how can i use the getOrElse function? I'm trying to join both files through the 1st column(id)

Comment: On a side note, you could do this easily without any mutable collections (which is preferred if there is no performance penalty which is the case here). Try removing the mutable maps one by one, you'll learn a lot from this process as you will be forced to think functional (using `map`, `zip`, `filter`, `flatMap` and so on).

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simpler approach using Scala's groupBy method on collections to create cogroups of related rows? You can then iterate over these groups and do whatever you wish. In the code below, I'm merely printing them:

```
val lines = for ((filename, idx) <- Array("TestScala1.txt", "TestScala2.txt").zipWithIndex) yield {
  Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toArray.map { e =>
    val splits = e.split(",").toList
    (idx, splits)
  }
}
lines.flatten.groupBy(e => e._2(0)).foreach(e => println(e._1 + " = " + e._2.toList))
```

Sample output:

```
Group 4 = List((0,List(4, Taio, Cruz)), (1,List(4, Black, 12, Laguna)))
Group 5 = List((0,List(5, Dan, Perez)), (1,List(5, Orange, 20, Pasay)))
Group 6 = List((0,List(6, Jen, Rose)))
Group 1 = List((0,List(1, Dom, Torreto)), (1,List(1, Red, 27, Makati)))
Group 2 = List((0,List(2, Lety, Betty)), (1,List(2, Blue, 22, Pasig)))
Group 3 = List((0,List(3, Bob, Dylan)), (1,List(3, Pink, 25, Pateros)))
```